# How can I automatically scale my OpenGL ES 2.0 window?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I'm writing an Android and iOS engine in C++ and currently focusing on Android with the NDK.

I'd like to render to a viewport of a smaller size (say 600x360) and automatically upscale this to the native rez (say 800x480.) Currently the smaller viewport displays in a lower corner of my screen with black regions.

My problem is I don't know of a simple way to do this *transparently* using the NDK. There is a `GLSurfaceview.setScaleX` (and Y) function in API level 11, which would be perfect, but doesn't exist in API level 9, which I am targeting. Another bad solution is to render to a FBO and blit that to the screen as a final step.

I am considering simply story a scaling matrix and asking the user of the engine (for now just me) to always multiply vertices by this when drawing to the screen. This would be similar to using `glPushMatrix`.

I searched for a while and couldn't find a good solution. Does anyone know how to help?

Comment: Your scaling solution won't change the resolution, it just upscales geometry, that is then rendered in full resolution. This si completely different to up-sclaling a small-res rendered image. I don't know why the FBO solution would be a bad one, as it's the perfect solution to your problem.

Comment: I could test it, but I was concerned about performance. I'm afraid that rendering to FBO then copying it would run into the fill-rate limitation on most devices.

Comment: How should you be able to upscale a low-res image to high-res otherwise. There is no other method than interpolating the low-res image, so you won't get around this anyway. And FBOs are the fastest solution as it prevents unneccessary copies. You cannot just render the low-res data to high-res magically, what colors should the intermediate values (missing in the low-res) have. You need some kind of pre-storage followed by interpolation.

Comment: Maybe there isn't in OpenGL, but I was hoping if there wasn't then there would be a way in Android. Note that as I said, there is a way in API level 11.

Comment: The question is, if this API level 11 way is actually faster than the FBO approach? But maybe, I have to admit I have no real Android experience (that's why I didn't dare to answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is get the **SurfaceHolder** from **GLSurfaceView**, [GLSurfaceView.getHolder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#getHolder%28%29) and then set the resolution you desire by calling [SurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(width, height)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setFixedSize%28int,%20int%29).

In my case the GLSurfaceView has a **FrameLayout** root which fills the screen, I am not sure if thats required - I have it because I add other elements on top - but if you set the size and it doesnt fill the screen then you know what's missing!

Using a *FrameBuffer* is also a valid way and you could draw some cool effects with it as well, the way above is just faster when the only thing you want to do is scale the rendering down (or possibly up? I haven't tried).

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for nailing the answer, I searched and could not find this solution.

Comment: You have to be overly familiar with the Android interfaces, I found it by accident while watching one of the Google I/O presentations on Games/OpenGL|ES - I think the 2010 event.